# How to capture data from multiple form search fields in one variable

Tags: php, forms

I have an html search form with multiple fields like select, textarea and text inputs. I need the values from all the fields to be stored into $input in the php search form but I'm not sure how to store them into one variable called $input on the php page.

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="http://example.com/search/">
Seach for: <input type="text" name="find" /> <input type="submit"  
name="search" value="Search" />
Search for movies by Type
<select name="find">
<option value="Sci-Fi" selected>Sci-Fi</option>
<option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
<option value="Drama">Drama</option>
</select>
</form>

//on search.php need to 'find' to be data from several form inputs
$input = $_POST['find'];
```

Comment: What do you want `$input` to contain if the user has filled in multiple fields? If you want them concatenated, use `.`.

Comment: I updated the code to show html form to help better explain what I am trying to do. Want user to be able to choose from a select box or type a keyword or do both, and have all the input stored in $input in the search.php page because all the code there is based on all the date being stored in just one $input variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you give multiple inputs the same name, `$_POST['find']` will just contain the input from one of them (the last one, I think). You need to either give them different names, or you can end the name with `[]`. When you do the latter, PHP will put all the inputs into an array.

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="http://example.com/search/">
Seach for: <input type="text" name="find[]" /> <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
Search for movies by Type
<select name="find[]">
    <option value="Sci-Fi" selected>Sci-Fi</option>
    <option value="Comedy">Comedy</option>
    <option value="Drama">Drama</option>
</select>
</form>
```

With this, you can do:

```
$input = implode(' ', array_filter($_POST['find']));
```

`array_filter` will remove any empty values, then the rest will be concatenated together with space between them.

Comment: tried that... i get error array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, null g and  implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments

Comment: Sounds like you didn't change all the `name="find"` to `name="find[]"` in the HTML.

Comment: Correct. Just did that, but same issue as with Silences answer above. It will return results from the select field if I leave the input field blank. But if I enter a key word in the input field then I get no results regardless of the select field. Odd. It does give me results from input field if I don't also have the select field as part of the query.

Comment: You changed the name in both the `<input>` and the `<select>`, right? I'm pretty sure it should work.

Comment: Yes I did. I just don't get any results if I enter a search word in the input field with this approach.

Comment: It shows array(2) {
[0]=>
string(0) “”
[1]=>
string(7) “Fiction”
}   This means to me that it is doing an array for each of the two input types, but it is no capturing the string value of the input field. somehow the second select input field keeps the text input from being brought over to the search.php

Comment: I just tried it on my server and it worked perfectly. `[0]` is what I typed into the input field, `[1]` is the menu choice.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Hmm. Just doesn't work on my end for some reason. Are you using some other code to get the string to display on the php page, like find[0][0]? Thanks for trying anyway

Comment: When you do the var_dump() do you get { [0]=> string(0) “” or do you see text between the ""?

Comment: Nevermind...I got it to show everything correct in the var_char(). The problem lies in the query not returning the actual rows for the input field

Comment: something wrong with my where perhaps? WHERE stories.story_name = '$input' OR stories.category = '$input' OR stories.genre = '$input'");

Comment: `=` does an exact match. If `$input` contains multiple categories, it won't match exactly.

Comment: so user LIKE instead of = for multidimensional? I was reading how I could try something like echo '|'.$products[0][0].'|'.$products[0][1].'|'.$products[0][2].'   Maybe that is my problem for the output...

Comment: You need to do a separate test for each word, and combine them with `OR`. `WHERE story_name LIKE '%$input[0]%' OR story_name LIKE '%$input[1]%'`

Comment: cool. Many thanks. And so if i had just two tests. It would be all in one long query string like WHERE story_name LIKE '%$input[0]%' OR story_name LIKE '%$input[1]%' OR WHERE type LIKE '%$input[0]%' OR type LIKE '%$input[1]%'

Comment: Yeah, you can to as many of them. You can use a loop or `implode` to build up those queries with all elements of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Make your $input an array. For example:

```
$input = array(
    "user" => $_POST['username'],
    "find" => $_POST['find'],
);
```

Or simply add everything to $input by doing:

```
$input .= $_POST['username'];
$input .= $_POST['find'];
```

Comment: I would love to do the second option here...that was my original apporach. Two separate input lines. But when I do that, I only get results if I leave the text input blank

Comment: I feel like the first option array might be working even though there are no results. I tried doing $input[0] in the SQL to get the results out of the array but I just get the wrong results.

Comment: Try for example: $input['username'].

Comment: Getting closer with  your $input = array approach. See new post with updated issues using that approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28804243/trouble-getting-data-from-multiple-fields-into-one-array

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
array_pop($_POST); // To delete Submit button from $_POST
foreach(array_filter($_POST) as $key=> $val)
{
    $input .= "$val";
}
?>
```