# Trouble getting data from multiple fields into one array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form that looks like this:

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="http://example.com/search3/">
Seach for: <input type="text" name="find[]" /> 
Search for stories by Type
<select name="find[]">
<option value="Fiction" selected>Fiction</option>
<option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
<option value="Essay">Essay</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

on php.search, I get the data by:

```
$input = array(
"find" => $_POST['find'],
);
```

It is almost working, except it doesn't put the results in the find array. Instead the data is going into the results in array2, probably b/c i named each field find[]. Here is the var_dump:

```
array(1) {
["find"]=>
array(2) {
[0]=>
string(5) “testing1”
[1]=>
string(7) “testing2”
}
}
```

I'm not sure why i leaves the find array blank in this case.

If I change the form so the find[] names as arrays become just find, 
then I get the data to go into the array named find like i want, HOWEVER, only the select form data will be captured. See var_dump for results and how I only get one result instead of two:

```
array(1) { 
["find"]=> string(7) “testing2” 
}
```

SO THE QUESTION IS...
How can I get the input AND select data captured in the find array?

Comment: set multi-dimenstional array, `find['input'][]` and `find['select'][]`

Comment: I do that in the search.php instead of $input = array(
"find" => $_POST['find'],
);  you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When naming field using square brackets `[]`, PHP automatically creates a nested array in the `$_POST` (or `$_GET`) array.

In your case, the value of $input['find'] is an array that has two numeric keys.

```
echo $input['find'][0];
echo $input['find'][1];
```

You can assume that index 0 holds the value entered in text input, the index 1 holds the value selected in the list.

If you skip the squre brackets in field names, browsers sends them to the server as follows:

```
find=value1&find=value2
```

PHP, when parsing data, first stores the `value1` under the key `find`, but when another `find` key occurs, it just overwrites the previous value with new `value2`.

Comment: Yes, i tried skipping the square brackets, and when I do those two echoes I get "Fi". I presume those are the first two letters of the word "Fiction" which is the default value of the select field

Comment: If I get rid of the squares (setting names as arrays), then select data overrwrites the input data as you said, so that's why I didn't do that. But regarding how I did do it above, do you have any thoughts on how I could store both values in the one array, or are you saying that I must have nested arrays to capture both values?

Comment: At least it works the way I have it in my code above. I just can't reference the data with that empty find array since the data is in the array(2). But I had to I summon that data in my query since it has no name? Something like input[ ][ ]?

Comment: actually, the two echoes do work--but the values in the form must have the [ ] brackets for it to do so. Thanks for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This, This will help you.

The name of fields should not be same.

```html
<form name="search" method="post">
  Seach for: <input type="text" name="search" /> 
  Search for stories by Type
  <select name="find[]" multiple>
    <option value="Fiction" selected>Fiction</option>
    <option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
    <option value="Essay">Essay</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  $input=array("find"=>$_POST['search'],'search'=>$_POST['find']);
  print_r($input);
}

?>
```

Comment: That just returns null. I tried it just like that and also tried it by editing the second part to be 'find'=>$_POST['search'] . Either way no luck.

Comment: if you don't fill the input text box, then it will surely returns null. Fill the text field and select options from the drop down list. you will get the multidimensional array which contains two arrays.

Like This: Array ( [find] => Hello [search] => Array ( [0] => Fiction [1] => Essay ) )

Comment: Yes, I definately filled out the text field and have a select field value too. It just gives null though and goes to message in code saying You forgot to enter a search term

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="search" method="post" action="">
Seach for: 
Search for stories by Type
<select name="find[]">
<option value="Fiction" selected>Fiction</option>
<option value="Non-Fiction">Non-Fiction</option>
<option value="Essay">Essay</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="find[]" /> 
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
<?php if(isset($_POST)){
    $input = array();
    $var =array();

     foreach ($_POST['find'] as $key => $value) {
        if(!empty($value)) {
            array_push($var, $value);
        }
        else{
            continue;
        }
     }
     $input = array(
"find" => $var,
);
     print_r($input);
}
```

Comment: Good idea. But when I run that code and var_dump I get this error and result: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() 
array(1) {
["find"]=>
array(0) {
}
}

Comment: if(isset($_POST['find'])&&!empty($_POST['find'])) instead of if(isset($_POST))

Comment: Thanks. Got it to go with my existing code in my question and just referencing the values with $q = ['find'][0]  etc